# Checkbox 'check' event

Tags: extjs

The following is in the initComponent of an extending class:

```
this.checkBoxArray[0].on('check(this.checkBoxArray[0]', false), this.enableAllCheckboxes, this);
```

It does not execute this.enableAllCheckboxes() after unclicking the checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be...

ExtJS 3.x:

```
this.checkBoxArray[0].on('check', this.enableAllCheckboxes, this);
```

ExtJS 4.x:

```
this.checkBoxArray[0].on('change', this.enableAllCheckboxes, this);
```

Comment: It doesn't work with with ExtJS 4.x, there you can use 'change' event.

Answer (score -2):

Add () to the function in the second argument